# io.Copy write: broken pipe for big file

Tags: go, copy, pipe, localtunnel

I have a file server and a proxy server through which I can access the file server via http

Simple file server :

```golang
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, "tmp/1.mp4")
    })

    if err := http.ListenAndServe("localhost:3000", nil); err != http.ErrServerClosed {
        log.Fatalf("HTTP server ListenAndServe: %v", err)
    }
```

and proxy server :

```
type Server struct {
    conn net.Conn
}

func (s *Server) Handle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    if err := r.Write(s.conn); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("req.Write ", err)
    }

    resp, err := http.ReadResponse(bufio.NewReader(s.conn), r)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("http.ReadResponse: %s", err)
    }

    defer func() {
        if resp.Body != nil {
            if err := resp.Body.Close(); err != nil && err != io.ErrUnexpectedEOF {
                fmt.Printf("resp.Body Close error: %s", err)
            }
        }
    }()

    copyHeader(w.Header(), resp.Header)
    w.WriteHeader(resp.StatusCode)

    if _, err := io.Copy(w, resp.Body); err != nil {
        if err == io.ErrUnexpectedEOF {
            fmt.Println("Client closed the connection, couldn't copy response")
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("copy err: %s\n", err)
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func (s *Server) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if err := s.Handle(w, r); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadGateway)
    }
}

func copyHeader(dst, src http.Header) {
    for k, v := range src {
        vv := make([]string, len(v))
        copy(vv, v)
        dst[k] = vv
    }
}

func main() {

    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:3000")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("net.Dial(tcp, localhost:3000) %s", err)
    }
    server := &Server{conn}
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8000", server))

}
```

if the file server distributes a small picture, then everything works correctly
if the file server is serving a large video file (1.mp4) then I get the error:

`copy err: readfrom tcp 127.0.0.1:8000->127.0.0.1:58964: write tcp 127.0.0.1:8000->127.0.0.1:58964: write: broken pipe`

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

`broken pipe` is the golang message linked to errno 32 `EPIPE`.

When dealing with a TCP connection, it is triggered when your process writes to a connection when the other end has already closed it.

---

Depening on what you mean by `"Client closed the connection"`, if your intention is to look for an indicator that the *outside client that connected to your proxy* closed its connection early, then you should be looking for `EPIPE` errors, not for `io.ErrUnexpectedEOF`.

Something like :

```
func isEPIPE(err error) bool {
    var syscallErr syscall.Errno
    b := errors.As(err, &syscallErr) && syscallErr == syscall.EPIPE

    return b
}


...

if isEPIPE(err) {
    fmt.Println("Client closed the connection, couldn't copy response")
} else {
    fmt.Printf("copy err: %s\n", err)
}
```

`io.ErrUnexpectedEOF` could probably occur in some situation, but it would be triggered from the connection with your file server, not from the connection initiated by the client.

Comment: Thanks for answering, why can the client close the connection, If browser keeps sending requests with range headers

Comment: why not ? :) there could be many reasons : if you have your own reverse proxy in front of your go server (say nginx or apache), check if there isn't a max response size parameter. Otherwise : debug from the client (web browser ?) you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The browser, when receiving an mp4 file, switches to streaming mode
That is, it starts sending http requests with the range header and expects a response with a status of 206

My proxy server always responds with the status 200

```
 copyHeader(w.Header(), resp.Header)
 w.WriteHeader(resp.StatusCode)
```

this forces the browser to disconnect the connection